# Need help debugging jscript event that shows/hides sections based on Opportunity Scope field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am trying to use a jscript event to show/hide tabs on my Opportunity form based on what is selected in the "Opportunity Scope".  I have made this an `OnLoad` event, as well as an `OnChange` event for when the `Opportunity Scope` field is changed.  However, I haven't been able to get the event to work.  I am fairly new to javascript and could use some help debugging.
Here is my code:

```
function HideShowOpportunityTabs() {
  OppScope = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“new_OpportunityScope”);
  if (OppScope.getValue() != null) {
    if (OppScope.getText() == ”Product”) {
      Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(“RecurringRevenue”).setVisible(false);
      Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(“FieldService”).setVisible(false);
    } else if (OppScope.getText() == ”Professional Services”) {
      Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(“RecurringRevenue”).setVisible(true);
      Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(“FieldService”).setVisible(true);
    }
  }
}
```

When I load the form, I receive the following error: "One of the scripts for this record has caused an error.  `HideShowOpportunityTabs` is not defined.

The `OnChange` event is not working either.  It does not cause an error, but the sections are not being hidden.

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: are you actually using jscript, a language that hasn't been used or updated in 25 years, or are you trying to abbreviate "javascript?"

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce.  your comment scared me for a second there.

Comment: can you add the code where you use `HideShowOpportunityTabs`  functions

Comment: Sorry, javascript not jscript.  I was able to solve the issue by changing the style of the double quotes to "".  I also had to change the "new_OpportunityScope" to all lowercase.  Thanks!

Comment: @TimG post it as answer & close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by changing the style of the double quotes to "". I also had to change the "new_OpportunityScope" to all lowercase. Thanks!